# Unable to edit the django table

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Unable to perform the update operation.

This function is for table update, but the code is not allowing me to pass the instance in the form because it is not a model form. Please suggest the changes.

class userForm(forms.Form):

```
SHIFT_CHOICES = ( ('D','DAY'), ('N','NIGHT') )
ADMISSION_FORM_STATUS = ( ('Y','YES'), ('N','NO') )
FORM_COMPLETE_STATUS = (  ('Y','YES'), ('N','NO'))
TRAINING_STATUS = ( ('Y','YES'), ('N','NO') )
STATUS = (  ('W','WORKING'), ('OL','ON_LEAVE'),  ('E','EXIT') )

employee_id = forms.CharField(max_length=8,required=False)
employer_id = CompanyModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=Company.objects.all(), label='Employer', widget=Select2Widget)
name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
uber_name = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False)
mobile = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
```

Comment: Can you show your model and view?

Comment: yes sure, added the model

Answer (score 0):

To bind data with the form fields, (not a model form), you will have to pass a dictionary with those specific fields to the form constructor.
In this case what you need to do is
Get the form data in a dictionary

```
driver = Driver.objects.get(employee_id = employee_id)
form_data = {'employee_id':driver.employee_id, 'employer_id', driver.employer_id, .., .., .} #all the fields in the form
AddDriverForm(initial=form_data)
```

Then while saving the data you should do it the same way you did for creating the driver.

Moreover, I would personally suggest you to use Model form for this case since you are going to put that data in the model anyways, it will surely save you the hassle.
Also, you might consider to normalize your model if its not a big deal.

Comment: I want to use the same URL to add the form data and edit form while editing it should come with the data. Your suggested changes are giving error "local variable 'employee_id' referenced before assignment".

Comment: Using the same url is not an issue, ModelForms can do that too.
and about the error, I cannot tell you without seeing what changes you made.
Since, employee_id is a field in instance from the Driver form, that is the only place where I've accessed it.
Did you make sure that you have inverted commas around it while adding in the dictionary?

Comment: Now an error is not there but still its rendering blank form. Could you please elaborate bit your solution?

Comment: I've tried to explain with a generic example, try if that helps you. If not ask me exactly what is it that you have difficulty with.

Comment: I have added a complete function where I am putting the logic (views.py). Could you check??

Comment: You did a small mistake here, 
initialised the form first in line 3 
form = AddDriverForm(request.POST)
and passed the same variable whereas
while initializing it with the dictionary you didn't save it in a variable

Comment: I have tried in all ways but it is not rendering the data.

Comment: Is it your personal project or something you are doing at work?
I mean can you share the repository?

Comment: No, not personal.

Comment: I have uploaded all the files i.e. model, form, view,  and addform.html

Comment: what I have to do is - list the data, add the data and edit/update the data with single addform.html and in one view function(that is add_drivers).

Comment: can you set a debug point right after we initialised the form and share the result?
you can send it on sid.kasat@gmail.com or +91 8888864468 (WhatsApp)

Comment: I do not know how to debug it. when I am trying to debug it, nothing is there... simply it's starting the proj.

Comment: what ide do you have?

Comment: On the left side of the line number, you will see a red dot when you hover there, just click and place a dot there
then start your project in debug mode
once it is started, you have to open the url which uses this view ie the update_driver_page
as soon as the the breakpoint is hit, you will have the control of the workflow. at that time you will be able to see all the variables on your debug console, we want to see form variable

Comment: Thank you, now the data is rendering properly on fields but  after submitting the form it throwing error "add_drivers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id' "

Comment: Yeah, so while calling the save function on the updated form instance django does not know which instance of model should be updated with the current data in the form. Since the form is not a model form, you must manually save the data in the model.

Comment: For that what approach should I follow??

Comment: Since this is the form for saving the updated data, there must be a way that you must've used to create the driver instance. You should check that

Comment: it must be somewhat like:

Driver.objects.create(employee_id = form.instance.employee_id, .., .., .., .. )
(in this case use Driver.objects.get(id=driverid).update(.., .., .., )

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your **model (DC) has an instance** (an entry):

*Superhero = Bruce, Butler = Alfred, Engineer = Lucius, car = Batmobile*

Your **form has**
*Superhero, Butler, Engineer*

(Notice that my form is missing the car field)

Now, suppose you want to change the name Butler to *Jarvis*

```
instance = DC.objects.get(id=8) #lets consider this as the id of the instance we have 
#what you need to do is save the required data in a dictionary in this case
form_data = {'Superhero':instance.Superhero, 'Butler':instance.Butler, 'Engineer': instance.Engineer } #we haven't passed the car field
#Also I think that passing extra fields must not be an issue but I haven't tried
UpdateForm(form_data)
```

This will render the data properly when the form is displayed.